# Android change database in new version off app

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Two month ago I published an app in the Google Play Store. Now I want to release a new version of the app but I have to modify the database. I have to create some new columns and have to delete some but now I'm scared that my users will lost their data. What is the best way of changing the databse without to lose any data?

Comment: It's very helpful if you post what you've tried so far, in as much detail (with as much code) as possible.  In short, you need to perform a database migration from the old structure to the new one - but it will be much much easier to help you if you can be more specific with your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use `SQLiteOpenHelper`, increment your database version you pass to its constructor. The `onUpgrade()` callback will be called so you can migrate your schema and user data properly.

You can use `ALTER TABLE` to add columns. To delete columns, you'll have to create a new table, copy the data over and then delete the old table. (You can use `ALTER TABLE` to rename tables, too.)

Comment: you can also usually leave the columns (provided they don't have annoying constraints) most of the time. Afaik, changing the type of column is really the only case where you absolutely need to recreate a table.